# how to improve the response time for the web service

Tags: performance, load-balancing

We have built a web services to serve map tiles like google map based on asp.net.

And The client require that the response time for 1000 concurrencies requests must be less than 1 seconds.

Now we use the loader balance hardware,We deploy the service to 4 servers using iis , then we use the loader balance hardware to distribute the requests to different server.

However someone suggest that we should not use the loader balance,since the browser request limits.

It is said that for a given domain,the number of the requests the browser can sent  at the same time is limited(maybe 10 or more).

So we should make our client application request to different tiles server directly.

Now,I am confused,which is the right way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It is said that for a given domain,the number of the requests the browser can sent at the same time is limited(maybe 10 or more)

1. This is only sort of true. Most browsers won't make more than a few request to the same domain. However, there is no set standard or defined limit and it is often configurable.
2. How do you know all your users will be accessing your service through the browser
3. What happens if you have 1000 concurrent users?

Use a load balancer